# How to remove program code from the posts of the stackoverflow data using python

Tags: python

I am working on a stackoverflow data project and I have created a database dump file from the xml files provided by stackexchange data dump for stackoverflow. Now I want to create a pickled file for the posts but I want to remove the programming code present in the posts.I just want the text of the post. How can I do it?

My current code status is:

```
import cPickle as pickle

result = list()

def dumpDB():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Path of data dump file')

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT Title, Body, OwnerUserID, Tags, Id FROM posts where Tags is not null')

    for item in cur:
        record = list(item)
        doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(record[1])
        record[1] = str(doc.text_content()) # this will strip the html tags
```

**NOTE:** If there is some error in explanation or code, I would appreciate your help in pinpointing them so as to correct them. I am new at this and as such there could be some mistakes.

**EDIT:** I saw the post which some suggested as having the answer for this problem, but I am not able to relate how to use the suggested solution in that post for my present issue. As suggested by the first comment below, I have to look for contents inside `<pre><code>` tags and I have to remove everything present inside them. How can I use the `remove()` to do that? I also looked at another way of doing it through `BeautifulSoup` but couldn't find  way to use it for my case

Comment: If you want to strip out formatted code (like the code block in your question), I'd suggest looking for `<pre>` and `<code>` tags before you strip the HTML from the post body. Alas, I don't know enough about `xml` processing to tell you how to do that.

Comment: @Blckknght is the formatted code present between `<prev>` and `<code>` tags? This will affect the xml  processing as most the lxml in built functions assume a consistent starting and ending of the tag, like if it starts with `prev` then it should end also with `prev`. I think my understanding is not wrong

Comment: It's not between the different tags, but rather, within opening and closing tags of one of those types (or sometimes both, nested, e.g. `<pre><code>stuff</code></pre>`). Perhaps my "and" should have been "and/or". I described both because I'm not sure if you want to filter all code (including inline things like `foo`) or just the big pre-foratted blocks.

Comment: @Blckknght I got what you meant to say. But that is the problem that how to remove contents between `<pre><code>stuff</code></pre>`. I looked at few examples but none had a combination of tags.

Comment: Well, if you remove the contents of the `<pre>` tags, the inner `<code>` tags will go too.